# Select only one of each id sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has been asked a million times before but due to the joins i am finding it hard to correctly write the code required

My SQL is

```
        SELECT DISTINCT
            newFvItems.Id, outerFvia.[UserRoleId], outerFvia.[DefaultStatusId], outerFvia.[CanBeAllocated], outerFvia.[CanCreate], outerFvia.[CanUpdate], outerFvia.[CanDelete], outerFvia.[CanSeeDraft], outerFvia.[CanSeeChecking], outerFvia.[CanSeeCompleted], outerFvia.[CanDispute], outerFvia.[CanResolveDispute], outerFvia.[CanAudit], 1, GETUTCDATE(), 393, GETUTCDATE(), 393, 0, outerFvia.[RecycleBinId], outerFvia.[FlowAccessId]
        FROM FlowVersionItemAccess outerFvia
            JOIN FlowVersionItems outerFvi ON outerFvi.Id = outerFvia.FlowVersionItemId
            JOIN FlowVersions outerFv ON outerFv.Id = outerFvi.FlowVersionId
            JOIN FlowVersionItems newFvItems ON newFvItems.FlowVersionId = 143
        WHERE outerFv.Id = 133
        AND outerFvia.Deleted = 0 AND outerFvi.Deleted = 0 AND outerFv.Deleted = 0
```

My desired output is 21 Rows, i get 27 if i remove DISTINCT i get 63

Sample data:

| ID | UserId | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | DateTime | val | DateTime | val | val | val | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 315 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 7 |
| 315 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 12 |
| 315 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 16 |
| 315 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 16 |
| 315 | 18 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 69 |
| 315 | 18 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 69 |

Expected data:

| ID | UserId | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | val | DateTime | val | DateTime | val | val | val | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 315 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 7 |
| 315 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 12 |
| 315 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 16 |
| 315 | 18 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 12/12/2022 16:53 | 393 | 0 | NULL | 69 |

You can see UserRoleId 7 and 18 are duplicated. I tried to simply group by UserRoleId but i get errors on FlowVersionItems.Id

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
> Column 'FlowVersionItems.Id' is
> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: There is no `GROUP BY` in your attempt, and you have a `DISTINCT` anyway, so adding a `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense. **Consumable** sample data, not an image, and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. You are joining to rows that have different values for some columns, eg `cancreate 0 or 1`, you need to decide *which* of those values you want with the approprate aggregation, min, max etc.

Comment: i have removed the images and added a table, i want the newer of the two for 7 and 18, this is only a portion of my sample data but enough to explain what is needed.

Comment: "I want the newer of the two for 7 and 18", and those two lines have the SAME date (and time), so which one of those 2 lines do you want?

Comment: Oops that's my fault with my mocked up data the later entry would also have a higher id

Answer (score 1):

Remove `DISTINCT`, add `GROUP BY newFvItems.Id` at the very end of query and define aggregating functions (MIN, MAX,...) for all columns you return.

`DISTINCT` finds all unique combinations of all columns, while you need just one column.

Alternatively, leave only `DISTINCT newFvItems.Id` in the select part - depends on what you actually need.

Comment: i have added tables to my question to better explain it.

Comment: could you provide an example script because i just get errors when i try use group by then wrap fields with min/max. Sorry if this is simple and im just not getting it.

Comment: What error do you get? Make sure you either include field into GROUP BY statement or use some aggregate function.

`SELECT a, b, c FROM tbl GROUP BY a` won't work. But `SELECT a, MAX(b), MIN(c) FROM tbl GROUP BY a` or `SELECT a, b, MIN(c) GROUP BY a, b` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solid approaches to this and i thought i would post my solution that i ended up using to hopefully help someone else. The group by solution is good and does provide the correct answer too but this fits an edge case better.

```
SELECT
    newFvItems.Id,
    outerFvia.[Id],
    outerFvia.[UserRoleId],
    outerFvia.[DefaultStatusId],
    outerFvia.[CanBeAllocated],
    outerFvia.[CanCreate],
    outerFvia.[CanUpdate],
    outerFvia.[CanDelete],
    outerFvia.[CanSeeDraft],
    outerFvia.[CanSeeChecking],
    outerFvia.[CanSeeCompleted],
    outerFvia.[CanDispute], outerFvia.[CanResolveDispute], outerFvia.[CanAudit], 1, GETUTCDATE(), 393, GETUTCDATE(), 393, 0, outerFvia.[RecycleBinId], outerFvia.[FlowAccessId]
FROM FlowVersionItemAccess outerFvia
    INNER JOIN FlowVersionItems outerFvi ON outerFvi.Id = outerFvia.FlowVersionItemId
        AND outerFvi.Deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN FlowVersions outerFv ON outerFv.Id = outerFvi.FlowVersionId
        AND outerFv.Deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN FlowVersionItems newFvItems ON newFvItems.FlowVersionId = 143
        AND newFvItems.Deleted = 0
        AND newFvItems.[Order] = outerFvi.[Order]
WHERE outerFvia.Deleted = 0
AND outerFv.Id = 133
```

Here is the group by solution too.

```
    SELECT
        newFvItems.Id, 
        outerFvia.[UserRoleId], 
        MAX(outerFvia.[DefaultStatusId]), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanBeAllocated] As tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanCreate] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanUpdate] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanDelete] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanSeeDraft] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanSeeChecking] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanSeeCompleted] as tinyint)), 
        MAX(CAST(outerFvia.[CanDispute] as tinyint))
        --, MAX(outerFvia.[CanResolveDispute]), MAX(outerFvia.[CanAudit]), 1, GETUTCDATE(), 393, GETUTCDATE(), 393, 0, MAX(outerFvia.[RecycleBinId]), MAX(outerFvia.[FlowAccessId])
    FROM FlowVersionItemAccess outerFvia
        JOIN FlowVersionItems outerFvi ON outerFvi.Id = outerFvia.FlowVersionItemId
        JOIN FlowVersions outerFv ON outerFv.Id = outerFvi.FlowVersionId
        JOIN FlowVersionItems newFvItems ON newFvItems.FlowVersionId = 143
    WHERE outerFv.Id = 133
    AND outerFvia.Deleted = 0 AND outerFvi.Deleted = 0 AND outerFv.Deleted = 0 AND newFvItems.Deleted = 0
    group by newFvItems.Id, outerFvia.[UserRoleId]
```

Hopefully me posting the solutions i came up with helps someone else, i know this question gets asked a lot and if it wasn't for the joins it would be a lot easier.